# Find the position of a character in a Microsoft Word document using VBA, without using the Range

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, character

*Hi Stack Fellas*, as I understand, in ms-word the "Range" refers to a placeholder in the string, whereas the actual position refers to the characters themselves as I illustrated in this picture
[image]

if we know the actual position we can refer to its correspondent range by shifting the its start by (-1) as in `range start= actual position start -1` and vice versa,

**my question:**

is there a way we can refer to the actual position of characters without using the range ?

Comment: "Actual position of characters" in relation to what?

Comment: @Comintern, in relation to the start of the body string

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done without traversing the complete document `Range`.  The indexing of a `Range` object includes positions that aren't representable in the `Range.Text`.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of your question, so it's difficult to be sure what you're really asking. Perhaps a practical example of how you'd use the information would help... However, I agree with @Comintern 's comment that using the Range(Index) is unreliable, since not everything in the text can actually be seen on the screen and, depending on how your code works, the Range(index) may not be addressing the characters you think it will.

Comment: @Cindy Meister, thanks for the info

Comment: @CindyMeister - It's Comintern's 2nd Law of Word Thermodynamics: "Any action taken on the Text property of a Range decreases the amount of information that the two hold in common".

Comment: @Comintern ROFL!! How true...

Comment: @Comintern is that law universal or applicable for closed systems only :)?

Comment: Only for closed systems.  However, you can increase the total energy in the system only through VBA or user input.  Otherwise, the 1st Law of Word Thermodynamics would be violated.